# Guardar Código QR después de ser generado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

me interesa saber como guardar el código QR ya que lo generé y mandarlo llamar en el metodo POST.

Esto funciona perfectamente y es con lo que generé el código QR. He buscado info en internet pero solo he encontrado como generarlo pero no como guardarlo.

HTML

```
 <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => item.StockNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " }) 
      @Html.EditorFor(model => item.StockNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new{@class = "form-control qr-url"}})            
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.StockNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
       <button type="button" id="btnQR" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btnQR">Generate QR Code</button>
 </div>
 <div id="qrcode" class="text-center"></div>
```

//QR CODE

```
    $('.btnQR').on('click', function () {

        // Clear Previous QR Code
        $('#qrcode').empty();

        // Set Size to Match User Input
        $('#qrcode').css({
            'width': $('.qr-size').val(),
            'height': $('.qr-size').val()
        })

        // Generate and Output QR Code
        $('#qrcode').qrcode({
            render: 'canvas',
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
            text: $('.qr-url').val()
        });
    });
```

Espero obtener su ayuda.

Comment: Qué es lo que te falla?

Comment: Quiero guardarlo, he buscado info en inter sobre como guardarlo el código despues de ser generado pero no encuentro info. Quiero guardar el código QR.

Comment: Imagino que estas generando este código QR en base a algún código hexadecimal o similar... la pregunta es si deseas guardar la IMAGEN del código QR o quieres guardar el código que utilizas para generar dicho código

Comment: que libreria estas utilizando ?

Comment: deseo guardar la imagen,  esta librería <<qrcode.min.js>>

Comment: pero de que url obtienes la libreria? porque buscando hay varias librerias que usan el mismo nombre de .js

Comment: Lo quieres guardar donde?? en el lado del server?? o que el usuario pueda descargarlo??, porque si es en el lado del sever.... puedes utiliza un nuget para crearlo alli mismo como archivo local en el server, solo necesitas el valor del QR $('.qr-url').val()

Answer (score 1):

Si es en el lado del server, te paso este ejemplo:

[Proyecto de ejemplo MVC](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Vj_MzhjsJtGDr0gpi4WIeOmymiHRAgCL)

Estoy utilizando este nuget:
[Nuget QR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/QRCoder/)

1. Agregue el nuget a la solución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Cree un controller llamado QR y agrege lo siguiente:

   ```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using QRCoder;

    namespace QRTest.Controllers
    {
        public class QrController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Qr
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";


                QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
                QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(fileName, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
                QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
                Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);

                var folder = "Qrs\\";
                var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(folder);
                qrCodeImage.Save(path + fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg );

                ViewBag.QrFile =folder + fileName;

                return View();
            }


        }
    }
   ```
3. Cree la vista Index para el controller QR:

   ```
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <img src="@ViewBag.QrFile"/>
   ```

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al refrescar la pagina se guarda en el server y se muestra en el cliente un nuevo QR.

Saludos, espero que a alguien le sea de utilidad este ejemplo.

Comment: Como dirían mis hermanos de Argentina: Sos grande Cristina :D gracias por el aporte

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+ me muestra ese error al momento de guardar la imágen

Comment: Utilizando  el ejemplo que pase?? o en tu código? tendrás que validar que la ruta exista y que el usuario que esta corriendo la aplicación tenga permiso sobre esta ruta, silo tienes en IIS puedes ver el apppool de tu app y que usuario esta corriendo ese apppool, puede network user, iis user, local service, etc...

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu código?, hay algo relacionado con liberar la memoria y la forma como estas guardando y leyendo los archivos, el probable que quieras guardar el mismo archivo... en cuyo caso deberías borrar el anterior.